# Is there any way of comparing latin with Cyrillic?

Tags: oracle

In **table1** *column1's* data type is string. However values of column1 is written in latin or Cyrillic. IN **table2** *column1* is only in latin. Is there any way of converting Cyrillic to latin while comparing in oracle.
Here is my simpe example. Note: row numbers are more than 25 million.

Search values matches only (if value is Cyrillic convert to latin and compare)

[image]

Comment: Yes. I ment Cyrillic.

Comment: I think this could be difficult, because Cyrillic has more letters than latin and some letters do not have a one-to-one translation to latin. The [TRANSLATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions232.htm#SQLRF06145) may help.

Comment: I'm not sure it will help. Number of rows over more

Comment: You might want to consider sound-alike matching algorithms such as [SOUNDEX](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SOUNDEX.html#GUID-9C43625B-70CA-4B43-AE22-5EC2A02192F8). Unfortunately this is probably not defined for Cyrillic, but you might be able to use your approximate translation from Cyrillic -> latin and then use SOUNDEX or a similar algorithm. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare
  cyr_name nvarchar2(4000) := 'Стивен';
  lat_name nvarchar2(4000) := 'Stiven';
  translit nvarchar2(4000);
  
begin
  translit := translate (upper(cyr_name),'АБВГДЕЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФЬЫЪЭ','ABVGDEZIJKLMNOPRSTUF''Y''E');
    translit:= replace(translit, 'Ж', 'ZH');
    translit:= replace(translit, 'Х', 'KH');
    translit:= replace(translit, 'Ц', 'TS');
    translit:= replace(translit, 'Ч', 'CH');
    translit:= replace(translit, 'Ш', 'SH');
    translit:= replace(translit, 'Щ', 'SH');
    translit:= replace(translit, 'Ю', 'YU');
    translit:= replace(translit, 'Я', 'YA');
  
  
  dbms_output.put_line('LAT: '|| INITCAP(lat_name));
  dbms_output.put_line('CYR: '|| INITCAP(cyr_name));   
  dbms_output.put_line('TRANSLIT: '|| INITCAP(translit));
  
  --This function calculates the measure of agreement between two strings, and returns a score between 0 (no match) and 100 (perfect match).
  dbms_output.put_line('Similarity: '|| UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(INITCAP(lat_name), INITCAP(translit)));    
end;
```

**Output:**

```
LAT: Stiven
CYR: Стивен
TRANSLIT: Stiven
Similarity: 100
```

Comment: you can put this into where section of your query something like `select * from ... where UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(INITCAP( latin_name), INITCAP( translate (... here the code from above ... ))) = 100`   .... or you can create your own function that returns level of similarity between cyr and latin names